# Dell XPS 13 Broadcom PCIe wireless card not recognized

Tags: drivers, debian, broadcom

Setting up a fresh Debian install (testing), I ran into issues with my network card. Because my laptop was originally a Windows one, I don't have the Intel network card but am stuck with the Broadcom one.

I know which model my wireless card is and which firmware it uses but somehow my card is not even recognized correctly. My system is up to date, I have rebooted multiple times. My card's device ID (`lspci`) should be

```
PCI device ID: 14e4:43a3
```

but as you can see below this is not the case. This fact surprises me, since Arch Linux works just fine.

```
$ sudo lspci -nnv
3a:00.0 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:8100] (rev 08)
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at dc200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-81-ff-ff-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
```

Comment: Find out which driver arch uses. `lshw` And it is recommended to install debian with non-free firmwares: http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/weekly-builds/amd64/iso-cd/

Comment: @IporSircer I can't check that anymore, no more Arch on my laptop.

Comment: It has an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/739048/wireless-adapter-broadcom-14e443a3-does-not-work-in-ubuntu

Comment: @Darius No, in that case the device ID is shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing the [non-free firmwares](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/weekly-builds/amd64/iso-cd/) included by default as suggested by [IporSircer](https://superuser.com/users/607525/ipor-sircer).